# Встроить Control (InputBox или Button) в TaskBar Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, controls

Есть задача встроить элемент управления в панель задач Windows, но я не знаю как это реализовать. Может кто подскажет в какую сторону смотреть или что подробнее. Буду благодарен.

P.S.
Пишу на C# WPF

[image: Что-то на подобие поля поиска в Windows 10]

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and